# VideoView.setVideoURI Url works but Path doesn't

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview

I wanted to play a video from the sdcard in my own app. I use following code in my MainActivity.java:

```
package ch.innocampus.fixi.videoplayer;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        MediaController mediaController=new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        Uri video=Uri.parse("http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4");
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.start();

    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but if i download the video to my sdcard and replace the link in the Uri video=Uri.parse brackets to "sdcard/movie.mp4" i get the error "Sorry,this video cannot be played".

Does someone know a solution to this porblem?

Comment: `sdcard/movie.mp4` is not a valid path. Use a valid path, one that starts with `/`, and one that ideally is derived from a method (e.g., methods on `Environment`). And, use `setVideoPath()`, not `setVideoURI()`, with a path.

Comment: i changed it to `videoView.setVideoPath("/storage/31BB-C7BA/50.mp4");` but still the same error

Comment: You do not have read access to that path on Android 4.4+ devices.

Comment: how can i access my sdcard?

Comment: I am not certain that you can with `VideoView`. I would try `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, allow the user to pick the video content, then pass the resulting `Uri` to `VideoView` and `setVideoURI()`.

Comment: No, this isn't an option. Im using the app to open the video via qrcode, which contains the videopath. is there a directory in the internal storage which i can access?

Comment: "Im using the app to open the video via qrcode, which contains the videopath" -- the "videopath" can be different on different devices. "is there a directory in the internal storage which i can access?" -- if you mean [what the Android SDK refers to as external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), with `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, you have access to all of it.